# Windows 7 - Setting up the default taskbar items

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, deployment

I've been working on building windows 7 deployments and I've run into an interesting issue. I want to customize the pinned taskbar items after I finish the deployment. We have a number of different teams that use different programs. The "one size fits all" method of copying a user profile specified by [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;973289) does not fit our needs.

I've done a few google searches and I run across a ton of pages detailing how to customize the taskbar once a user has logged in but that's it. I basically need a way to modify the taskbar remotely or from a powershell script.

Comment: Update: I tried adding a shortcut to the following location (C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar). After a restart, there was no change to the taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only solution I ever found, and it requires a 
a program to be run on the first user logon, which will do the taskbar changes that you want. So programming is required.

For a .Net solution, see the article
[Pin and Un-pin items to/from the Windows 7 taskbar](http://blog.ananthonline.net/?p=37)
where a .cs file is attached that contains a class that can:

1. Figure out if a given executable is pinned to the taskbar
2. Un-pin it from the taskbar
3. Pin it back to the taskbar

The above article is based on another :
[Pin Items to the Start Menu or Windows 7 Taskbar via Script](http://blogs.technet.com/deploymentguys/archive/2009/04/08/pin-items-to-the-start-menu-or-windows-7-taskbar-via-script.aspx)
where a similar approach is described using vbs scripts.

Comment: I also found the following post that uses powershell: http://blog.crayon.no/blogs/ragnar/archive/2009/04/17/pin-applications-to-windows-7-taskbar.aspx